# "The attachable property not found in type " error while using a dependency property in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I am trying to do some sample applications to use Dependency Property in a DataGrid,but when i tried to run application I am getting an run time exception

> The attachable property 'SelectedColumnIndex' was not found in type
>   'CustomDependencyProperty'. [Line: 17 Position: 74]

This is the code i used to declare my dependency property

```
public class CustomDependencyProperty : DataGrid
{

    public static DependencyProperty SelectedColumnIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColumnIndex",
                                                                                                 typeof(object),
                                                                                                 typeof(DataGrid),
                                                                                                 new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int SelectedColumnIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(SelectedColumnIndexProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedColumnIndexProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my XAML code

```
<UserControl xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="BindingDictionary.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingDictionary"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:SimpleConverter x:Key="myConverter"></local:SimpleConverter>
    </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Responses}" 
                      local:CustomDependencyProperty.SelectedColumnIndex="{Binding Index,Mode=TwoWay}">
        </sdk:DataGrid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="DisplayIndex" Text="{Binding Index}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I am unable to figure out what excatly is the problem.Is there anything wrong in the way I declare a dependency property?

Please help.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) here. Try changing

`DependencyProperty.Register`

to

`DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached`.

Also, `typeof(object) should be typeof(int)`.

**UPDATE**

Yes, the above will fix your problem, but I think you don't really need an attached property here as your class is extending the `DataGrid` class. A normal dependency property is all you need. So keep your existing code and change

```
typeof(object),typeof(DataGrid),
```

to

```
typeof(int),typeof(CustomDependencyProperty),
```

and in your xaml, you can just use this extended class directly, something like this,

```
<local:CustomDependencyProperty SelectedColumnIndex="{Binding Index,Mode=TwoWay}">
```

You might want to change the name 'CustomDependencyProperty' to be something more meanful like `ExtendedDataGrid`.

So I think the conclusion is you normally have two ways of creating a bindable property, either by extending the control and creating a normal dependency property, or by creating a static class with an attached property.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: yes indeed, initially it was an attached property.I changed that to a dependency property to see what excatly is the diffrence between an dependency property and an AttachedPropety.I think now I know what went wrong :)

Comment: I have updated the answer, hopefully it will give you some clarification on the difference of ap and dp. :)

Comment: :marking this a 'answer' as it has got a better explanation :)

Comment: Thanks! Yours is a valid answer too. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I can answer this question now.This exception just explains what exactly is the diffrence between an `AttachedProperty` and a `DependencyProperty`.

To use a dependency property **SelectedColumnIndex** I should redefine my `DataGrid` xaml like this

```
<local:CustomDependencyProperty x:Name="customGrid" 
                                 AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Responses}" 
                                 SelectedColumnIndex="{Binding Index, Mode=TwoWay}">
</local:CustomDependencyProperty>
```